# How to define in TypeScript output type which depends on optional parameter

Tags: typescript

I have tried the following but it doesn't work

```
export class Product {
    getItems: <T extends string | undefined>(itemId?: T) => T extends undefined ? Item : Item[];
}

// Test Cases
const item: Item = Product.getItems('id') // should return Item because parameter is present

const item: Item = Product.getItems() // should return Item[] because parameter itemId is omitted
```

Comment: Why not use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads): https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChkHIhwYQBcyAzmFKAOYDcuAvrrhAB4AOA9lGMgQAbOJUrIAClB4ATAK4IBeQsjoQw6CBkoAKYJlQyK1WiDoBKCpoxMVajZl2W0mANoBdW4XvXd+rYYA-MY09M7WyAA+LloeOPgqhFDqclAgOMzIolkgAJ5eBMxMrLhC6shcyAC8RBAA7pLS8oo65ky4APQdyAAqENTIAMKi-bgIPCAD-hhWmNUVAHQ+jjoA5MAyq+bIXVQAFjxyQjLIyWCp6REARhAIcHKUKFxwUCTq0MjA4lzJj+Bs40mAmmlFmsXc8y4S3UvlaO26lAORxOZwuMQwcRudweTxeb0gUE+BhOX2QPAw+kgMlwQA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with conditional types:

```
export class Product {
    static getItems: <T extends string | undefined = undefined>(itemId?: T) => T extends undefined ? Item[] : Item = null!
}

// Test Cases
const item: Item = Product.getItems('id') // returns Item because parameter is present

const item2: Item[] = Product.getItems() // returns Item[] because parameter itemId is omitted
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG8pgFxQM7ACcBLAOwHMoBfAKGogA8wB7A4KAYwBsBDXXKAAoEmAEwCu7NmmpRZeYN2BF2UMhGBxEuHAB4AKlAbwSI-vmLkoAHyhiTEAGakIIlLftOSLgHwAKIvAIMCIA-Dh6AJQo3lAGRhAm-HYijs6uIbCBANoAulA4mkioJGKcnACE1DTUAPQ1sRD4UADCvI3U7EwkTQGIBYFuQqISwAB0ahqBuL4A5EQiM1F1UATqYgTdmYhQAEYQ7NxiuNBg3ATcCOoQBFBE-GCrxyTAtJ3dbL0IAEz9iLmDwnEknG6kK0yW9VWwHWm0K-z2ByOJzOFyuN0+wVu-CYCAC8BEQA)

But a better solution would probably be to use overloads:

```
type Item = { p: string }
export class Product {
    static getItems(): Item[]
    static getItems(itemId: string): Item
    static getItems(itemId?: string): Item | Item[] {
      return null!
    }
}

// Test Cases
const item: Item = Product.getItems('id') // should return Item because parameter is present

const item2: Item[] = Product.getItems() // should return Item[] because parameter itemId is omitted
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG8pgFxQM7ACcBLAOwHMoBfAKAgA8wB7A4KAYwBsBDXXKABQKMAJgFc2rNNSgy8wLsCJsoZCMDiJcACgCUODQgDaAXWmz8CpSrUHtReAhjCc+YuT2wHZmRcXLV6g52Dk4A-C6EpGQeBlAAPp6IJujesgRqogQkUCSiHBwAhKk0NNQA9GVQACoQ+FAAwjy11GyMJHX2iPoOKAJCYhIAdAG2WgDkRMJjOlAVeAAWjHnCUOnAmdmxAEYQbFyiuNBgXARcCGoQBFBEfGDphyTA1C1tHQ4ATN1Jxr2CIuLAYY2IK6WaVXCLZarDJZRJGH47PYHI4nM4XK6dRwrG5QRgIezwYRAA)